# Is it possible to set material 2 placeholder font-size using mixins?

Tags: angular, placeholder, mixins, angular-material2

i am using material2 on my Angular 4 project . 
I`d like to set placeholder and text size for inputs and md-select global in my project using a mixin.

I am using the code below to set font-size in md-select and it works as expected.. but when I am trying styling $input placeholder in the same way it doesn`t affect at all...

anybody know how to do this?

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $subheading-2:  mat-typography-level(14px, 1.125, 400)
);

@include mat-core($custom-typography);
```

i am finding a temporary solution to set this styles global in my css, but i thing this is not propper way...

```
.mat-form-field-placeholder {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  line-height: 28px !important;
}
.mat-input-element {
  font-size:14px !important;
}
```